# R vectorization without ifelse

Tags: r

```
a <- array(1:18, dim=c(3,3,2))
a1 <- which( a >= 17, arr.ind = T)
a1im <- cbind(a1[,1] - 1, a1[,c(2,3)])
#ADVDOMiM is a logical vector
```

I would like a better vectorization than this one:

```
a[a1im] <- ifelse( a[a1] >= 5 & ADVDOMiM, a[a1], a[a1im])
```

I would like something like this:

```
 a[a[a1] >= 5 & ADVDOMiM] <- a[a1]
```

but it doesn't work( i need to change the result in a[a1im], but i don't know how to do it)

Comment: When creating `a1` you test `a >= 17` and then again `a[a1] >= 5`. The `a[a1] >= 5` can be removed?

Comment: Maybe you change getting `a1` to `a1 <- which( a >= 17, arr.ind = T)[ADVDOMiM,]` and then `a[a1im] <- a[a1]` can come to the same result like with `ifelse`.

Comment: i need a general answer, because `a >= 17` was just an examples. Same story for `a[a1] >= 5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to subset `a1im` and `a1` with `a[a1] >= 5 & ADVDOMiM` to avoid the `ifelse`:

```
i <- a[a1] >= 5 & ADVDOMiM
a[a1im[i,]] <- a[a1[i,]]
```